# How does kubernetes work from within a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

How does a Kubernetes run (kubectl get no) from within a docker container?

I know that it has to talk with the API server, but nowhere can I find a config file containing details of this (like .kube/config file found under my user)

I've done an env to check out what variables are set.
I've gone to the home directory which has a .kube directory but no config file.

Comment: kubernetes is a container orchestration system. it is meant to run docker containers, not to run from within a docker container! can you better explain your question?

Comment: Are you trying to talk to the Kubernetes API from inside a pod running in that same Kubernetes cluster, or to access it from “outside”?

Comment: We are trying to talk to the Kubertnetes API from inside a pod running in that same Kubernetes cluster??

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/)

> The recommended way to authenticate to the apiserver is with a service account credential. By kube-system, a pod is associated with a service account, and a credential (token) for that service account is placed into the filesystem tree of each container in that pod, at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

When kubectl is connecting with api using serviceaccount - token is placed in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`

> When you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is automatically assigned the default service account in the same namespace

When you perform "**config operation**" with **kubectl** like:

```
kubectl config set-context test
```

**.kube/config** will be created automatically.

You can pass also different **serviceAccountName** into your pod and auto mount token like:

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: <your_service_account>
  automountServiceAccountToken: true
```

You can find more information about Configure Service Accounts for Pods [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/).

Hope this help.